# Angular stepper form not valid after programmatically setValue

Tags: angular, angular-material2

This is my stepper:

```xml
    <mat-vertical-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper>
      <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
        <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select formControlName="firstCtrl" placeholder="Name" (selectionChange)="onChange($event)" required>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let device of deviceList" [value]="device">
                {{device}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
          <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperNext [disabled]="!firstFormGroup.valid">Next</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </mat-step>
      <mat-step>
        ....
      </mat-step>
    </mat-vertical-stepper>
```

This is my component code:

```js
        export class Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {

          @ViewChild('stepper') private stepper: MatStepper;
          deviceList: any;

          constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

          ngOnInit() {
             this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
             firstCtrl: new FormControl(
              '', [Validators.required])
             });

             this.deviceList = ["Device 1", "Device 2", "Device 3"];

             this.firstFormGroup.controls['firstCtrl'].setValue("Device 2", { onlySelf: true});

             this.stepper.next();
          }
        }
```

For some reasons, the form is not valid after setting the value by `setValue().`
Therefore the 'next' button is not activated and `stepper.next()` don't work too of course. If I manually change the select box to 'Device 1' it changes instantly to valid. I think there is a step I have missed to make the form valid after programmatically changing the value.
Anyone could tell me my mistake?

I want to prefill three forms, one in each step of my three-step-stepper.

Thank you and best regards!

Comment: Try removing `{onlySelf: true}` from `setValue()`

Comment: @xyz After removing it, it works with the validation. But after this.stepper.next()  there is an error: "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". this.stepper.selectedIndex = 1 works but the previous step is not marked as completed (grey dot with step number instead of blue dot with pen)

Comment: I am not aware of the usage of `stepper`, sorry won't be able to help you with that.

Comment: @HansZimmer You want this? check on link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u99wd3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Abhishek Thank you but this is basically what I already have. After setting the value I want the stepper to perform next(). So after loading the component, there is a completet stepper at the last step. Hope its clearer now